# Running Program over Mac lockscreen

Tags: macos, mac

I was wondering if there is any way to run any program on top of lock screen, so the pc is still locked but there is some kind of program running with UI, that you can interact with, without having to unlock the device.

Comment: Actually there is, the program has to use a special launchctl namespace provided by Apple for that purpose. I already read exactly how to do it, but it was last year. I will try to find the source document [I have found it while searching on google and it was very detailed]. Sorry but now I don't remember the web-address, and I have to look at my annotations. I post here when I find it.

Comment: @Prado...thanks mate. Awaiting the link to the same :)